# integrating angularjs with spring

Tags: angularjs, spring

I am trying to integrate AngularJS with Spring.I have addded app,js into resource folder.I think the location is proper but still for some reason i am getting this error

```
http://localhost:8080/DFDemo/resources/angular/app.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

<%@ page session="false"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload File Request Page</title>     
<script        
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js">        

</script>
<script src="resources/angular/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h1>Data Finder Batch upload</h1>
    <br /> <input type="file" name="file" /><br /> <br />
     <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
     <input type="hidden" value="hygiene" name="jobname" />
</form>

</body>
```

and following is my folder structure
[image]

Can anyone tell me whats wrong in this?

Comment: Where is app.js getting deployed from?

Comment: Its in WebContent/resources/angular folder

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I got the solution.I just included this <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />  in my dispatcher-servlet.xml